# Computing Fourier transform of $e^{-ax^2 - b|x|}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, gaussian-integral

recently I've been working on some estimation problems in $L_2$ space and came across the problem of computing the following Fourier transform for constants $a,b>0$:
$$
F(w) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\sqrt{-1}w x\right) \exp(-ax^2 -b|x|)\, dx.
$$
**What I tried**:

We can use the fact that a Fourier transform of the product is a convolution of Fourier transforms. Fourier transforms of the Gaussian and Laplacian densities are known. We get the following:
$$
F(w) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4a}\right)
\frac{2b}{b^2 + (x-w)^2} dx.
$$
I spent some time searching through the literature and various tables of integrals, but could not find a closed-form expression for this one.

**What I need**:

I'll be glad to have any sort of closed-form expression. Perhaps, it will depend on erf $\Phi(x)$ (error function), which is also fine for me!

Comment: Hint: Split your interval of integration at $x=0$ afterwards, complete the square and then use the definition of the errorfunction.

Comment: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf this reference might be useful

Comment: @tired, thanks for a reply. Regarding your first comment, I believe you mean to apply this tricks directly to the Fourier integral. Unfortunately, when you split the limits of integration you will end up with the modified form of a Fourier integral of a Gaussian measure, i.e. something like $\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-x^2} e^{-\sqrt{-1} xy} dx$, which I again don't know how to compute.

Comment: It works exactly the same as in the real case no worries